# using Sql Management Studio 2008 list past connections

Tags: login, sql-server-2008, ssms

when you open up sql management studio you can select server, and get a list of remembered connections.  I don't care about getting pw and but I would like a list of remembered or past connections.   I am migrating my laptop today and need that list (or would REALLY REALLY like it :) )

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions of Windows and SQL Server, that list is stored in:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\<version>\SqlStudio.bin.
```

It's not in a format that you can easily extract, but you can copy the entire file to your new machine.